# ReactJS heavy load application performance issue

Tags: performance, google-chrome, reactjs, firefox, google-chrome-devtools

I am looking for some advice on how to track application performance; the application is developed using ReactJS, and I am building it with webpack.

First of all I will just present what I have done and what the application is expected to do:

- I need to render a lot of, let's just call them widgets, that update real time presenting a lot of data. So, on a scale, I would say each widget renders about 50 to 80 values, these updates might be received from the server side all at once, so they should happen instantly when data is received. Consider I might have around 25 to 30 widgets that need to update real time.

Let me tell you a little bit about the implementation:

- I have used the smart/dumb pattern for ReactJS components
- The actual data is stored in application state and is distributed by the smart components to dumb components through props
- I am using Pure Render Mixin to avoid unnecessary rendering
- Also using Immutable data so that I will ensure Pure Render Mixin is working accordingly, that is, being accurate in determining if a render is necessary and at the same time be fast, really fast.
- There are no weird bindings of callbacks, that might determine re-rendering of components, this is double checked already.

Now the issues I am having:

- with about 5-6 widgets, meaning around 400-500 values that need to render each second, it works very well in Chrome and decent in Firefox.
- adding about 25-30 widgets gets the application to still work decent in Chrome, but it starts to act slow in Firefox, by slow I mean user interaction that might even get a delay of around 1 second. That is really unacceptable.

What I have tried:

- use Chrome dev tools to measure the performance; that didn't help too much, what I could see though, is that everything is alright. And there is no way I could read all the graphics this tool provides. (And I've read a lot of articles about it)

  - tried to use Firebug in Firefox. That's an amazing tool, but not in this case; just by opening it with the above mentioned load (30 widgets) gets Firefox to freeze... and the profiler gave me nothing)
  - on a last resort, I have used the default dev tools from Firefox, it has a performance tab. That got me some information of what parts of the application has the most load on the browser. It seemed it was some heavy computing determining min/max of an Immutable.List.

Unfortunately the application still has performance issues, and it is of high importance to get it working perfect, and Firefox profiler doesn't give me any other leads.

So my questions would be:

- what would be the next action to take in order to determine performance issues? (as much as possible where they are: class/method/at least file)
- did you guys use any performance testing tool that gives you an insight of what the hell is happening?
- is there something else to consider to improve the overall functionality, especially targeting multiple browsers? (Firefox, Chrome, IE11)

Comment: Are there any hidden components using display: 'none'?

Comment: Is each widget bound to one state which updates ever second? That would be a lot to ask of React because even with the Pure Render Mixin when the state updates all 30 widgets would have to update at the same time. Could you use flux such that each widget is only listening to the part of state that's relevant to it? Good question by the way.

Comment: @Rick, yes, sorry for the misunderstanding. Flux is used, data is stored in application state, each widget gets only data that is relevant of course. :) And, thanks!

Comment: @Janaka There are no hidden components using display: none.If part of the widget is not needed, it just isn't rendered.

Comment: I'd debug this by removing the PureRenderMixin from one of the widgets, adding your own `shouldComponentUpdate()` and then `console.log()` to see if 1. it's being called when it shouldn't be and 2. if the this.props === nextProps.

Comment: Yeah, thanks! I have already done that before posting this question. That's actually a very good way to see if there are any rendering that should not happen. Unfortunately the issue is more complex. It would have been great to have a tool to just tell you where you did wrong. :) I am close to break... myself not the issue :))